# Bash — выполнение *.sh скриптов

Tags: php, git, bash

Появилась необходимость задать жесткий путь при выполнении действий скриптом, а именно:

Есть PHP-файл, который выполняет обновление Web-директории из удаленного git-репозитория. Проблема в том, что путь он подставляет из того места, откуда он был запущен.

Теперь более подробно. Есть папки:

- **Удалённые origin-ы:**

  - `/home/sdc/projects/one.git`
  - `/home/sdc/projects/two.git`
- **Web-директории:**

  - `/home/sdc/webpath/one`
  - `/home/sdc/webpath/two`
  - `/home/sdc/webpath/git.update/index.php` (страница, которая делает `exec()` по `update.sh` скрипту. `update.sh` обязан находится в папках `one` и `two`)

Текст `update.sh`:

```
git pull origin master
```

Так вот. При выполнении `exec`-а получаю ошибку, которая говорит о том, что я не нахожусь в директории git-репозитория.
Правильно: так как путь я вижу следующий: `/home/sdc/webpath/git.update/`.

Вопрос:
Как подставить путь запуска программы из каталога, где расположен `update.sh`? (`/home/sdc/webpath/one` либо `/home/sdc/webpath/two`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос.

Если проблема в том, что бы сменить директорию, то:

```
cd /home/sdc/webpath/one
# что-то делаем
/home/sdc/webpath/git.update/update.sh
# если нужно вернуться в старую директорию
cd -
```

Если в том, что бы работать с git'ом из другой директории, то:

```
# вызываем скрипт с соответствующим environment
GIT_DIR=/home/sdc/webpath/one update.sh
```

Если, проблема в том, что из-под git hook'а не работают комманды из другого/клонированного репозитория, то:

```
# сначала очищаем текущую переменную GIT_DIR
# поскольку она указывает на bare репозиторий
unset GIT_DIR
cd /home/sdc/webpath/one
# ... и т.д.
```

Если проблема в том, что бы из-под php запустить скрипт с соответствующим PWD, то:

```
exec("cd /home/sdc/webpath/one && /home/sdc/webpath/git.update/update.sh");
```

Или через [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php):

```
$process = proc_open('/home/sdc/webpath/git.update/update.sh', $descriptorspec, $pipes, '/home/sdc/webpath/one');
```

Comment: Да, спасибо :) Прям в update.sh написал cd ../../../ и все пошло )))
Сорри, адово затупил :)